# Check tensorflow 2 eager execution status

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have an old Keras code that I've ported to tensroflow2 `tf.keras` with minimal changes. It now runs 2x slower on GPU but it is using the GPU. I have used

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

at the top of each of my scripts (I create the model and train it using separate `.py` files), but I suspect that eager execution might be getting turned on somehow.

I don't use a `fit_generator` but I do use `train_on_batch` and do the loop by hand because I'm training an adversarial network.

How can I check/ensure that eager execution has been off throughout? The main script I run is `train.py` which imports functions from other scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tf.executing_eagerly()` which returns `True` when eager execution is On. You can also use tensorboard to check the status of your GPU and inspect the problem in details to identify where might be the problem. These two links should give you more information.

[Tensorflow eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager)

[Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras)